# literature about permutation tests in linear mixed models to test fixed effects of categoircal variables under the null hypotheses

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, permutation-test

I'm currently analyzing a linear mixed model to model the effect of different treatments (two factors, both within and with multiple categories, e.g. treatment1_1, treatmen1_2, treatmen1_3, Treatment 2_1 ...) nested within each participant, who belong to different groups (between).

I have set up a random intercept model using `lme` in the `nlme` package, which looks roughly like this

```
lme(y ~ 1 + factor_within1*factor_within2*group, random = ~ 1 | ID)
```

where y denotes my dependent variable, factor_withinX denote the within factors (again, both categorical) and group denote the between factor (also categorical); ID is the number of each participant.

However, my dependent variable is slightly skewed and only contains values greater than 0. Thus, my residual plot looks not very convincing

[image]

Given that, I thought about using GLMM's with `glmer` in the `lme4` package. However, using different distribution families (e.g. gamma) with different link functions (e.g. identity) did not solve the situation (I investigated the residual distribution using QQ-Plots and fit Indices like the AIC).

In a last step I thought about doing a permutation test in order to get a non-parametric alternative to test my fixed effects in the original `lme` model.

**Three Questions:**

1. Is it reasonable to go for a permutation test as a non-parametric alternative in the given situation?
2. And if yes, how is it done? Is there literature covering that topic? So far I couldn´t find anything
3. And further: does anybody know a website/paper/book, giving a example on how to implement the procedure in R?

Comment: You wrote that your dependent variable is greater than 0, but does it also perhaps have an upper bound? If yes, then you could consider a Beta mixed effects model; see e.g.: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370205/r-lmer-3-time-point-longitudinal-data-non-linear-messy-residual-help .

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos I was under the impression that beta regression only works for (0,1), so what to do with the boundaries 0 and 1?

Comment: @ user2974951 Indeed, one transformation that is often used to tackle this is $y^* = \{y (n - 1) + 0.5 \} / n$, where $n$ is the sample size. Otherwise, you could use something like a two-part Beta mixed model, with an extra model for the 0's and the 1's.